# Is $\mathbb{E} (X_i|Y_i = y_i)$ iid?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ iid and $u_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2_u)$.

$$ Y_i = X_i + u_i$$

Is $\mathbb{E}(X_i|Y_i = y_i)$ iid?

I believe yes because we are holding $Y_i$ constant, and $X_i$ is iid. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are iid if $y_i=y_j$ for all $i,j$.

In that case you introduce no dependence between $\mathbb{E}(X_i|Y_i = y_i)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_j|Y_j = y_j)$ for $i\neq j$ and they are all defined in the same way. Obviously, they have different distributions if $y_i\neq y_j$.

Comment: Then how can I find the plim of $n^-1\Sigma^n_{1}\mathbb{E}(X_i|Y_i)$?

Comment: @Rainroad Can you maybe reformulate your question? The formula seems nonsensical to me.